# Trying to remove NaN and round off totals

Tags: javascript

I'm brand new to JavaScript and am only taking the class as a requirement. I have to make an order form for this class that I almost have up and working, but $ NaN pops up in my final totals as I add quantities and I can't get the tax numbers and final total numbers to round off to two decimal places. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title> Order Form Project </title>
        <style>
      /* Style the input box */
            .tbl
            {
                border: 2px solid green;
            {
            .center
            {
                text-align: center;
            }
            .right
            {
                text-align: right;
            }
            .left
            {
                text-align: left;
            }
      .inBox
      {
        text-align: right;            
        width:      50px;             
        border:     1px green;  
      }

      /* Style the button */
      .btn
      {
        width:      90px;            /* Fixed size of 120px */
        font-size:  0.9em;            /* Larger font */
        font-weight:bold;             /* Bold */
                align: left;
      }
      .btn:hover 
      {  
        background-color: pink;       /* Change mouse over color */
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function count(a,p,s)
{
  a.line_sum[p].value = a.line[p].value * s;
  a.line_sum[p].value = Math.ceil(a.line_sum[p].value * 1000) /1000;
  a.line_sum[p].value = Math.floor(a.line_sum[p].value * 1000) /1000;
  a.line_sum[p].value = Math.round(a.line_sum[p].value * 100)/100;
  if(a.line_sum[p].value == "NaN")
  {
    alert("Error: Check for mistakes");
    a.line[p].value = a.line[p].value.substring(0, a.line[p].value.length-1);
    a.line_sum[p].value = a.line[p].value * s;
    if(a.line_sum[p].value == "0") a.line_sum[p].value = "";
  }
  else 
  {
    var gt = 0;
    for(i=0; i < a.line_sum.length; i++)
    {
      gt += Math.ceil(a.line_sum[i].value * 1000) /1000;
    }
    gt = Math.round(gt * 1000)/1000;
    a.grand_total.value = "$ " + gt;
    decimal(a);
   }
}

function get_data(a)
{
  // var order_data = "This Order is ...\n";
  // for(i=0; i < a.line.length; i++)
  // {
  //   if(a.line[i].value == "") a.line[i].value = "0";
  //   order_data += "Line " +i+ " = "+a.line[i].value +" Qty\n";
  // }
  // if(a.grand_total.value == "") a.grand_total.value = "Nil";
  // order_data += "Total Order Value = " + a.grand_total.value;
  // document.g.order.value = order_data; 

  var apples = 0 + document.getElementById("apples_total").value;
  var grapes = 0 + document.getElementById("grapes_total").value;
  var pears = 0 + document.getElementById("pears_total").value;
  var sub_total = 0;
  var tax_total = 0;
  var grand_total = 0;
  sub_total = +apples + +grapes + +pears;
  tax_total = +sub_total * +0.06;
  grand_total = +sub_total + +tax_total;

  debugger;
  document.getElementById("sub_total").value = sub_total;
  document.getElementById("tax_total").value = tax_total;
  document.getElementById("grand_total").value = grand_total;

}

function decimal(a)
{
  for(i=0; i<a.line_sum.length; i++)
  {
    var d = a.line_sum[i].value.indexOf(".");
    if(d == -1 && a.line[i].value != 0) a.line_sum[i].value += ".00";
    if(d == (a.line_sum[i].value.length-2)) a.line_sum[i].value += "0";
    if(a.line_sum[i].value == "00") a.line_sum[i].value="";
  }
  d = f.grand_total.value.indexOf(".");
  if(d == -1) f.grand_total.value += ".00";
  if(d == (f.grand_total.value.length-2)) f.grand_total.value += "0";
}

function send_data(g)
{
  get_data(document.a);
  if(document.a.grand_total.value == "Zero")
  {
    var conf = confirm("No items are entered");
    if(conf)g.submit(); else init();
  }
  else g.submit();
}
    </script>
        <body>
            <form name="a">
                <table color="solid green" border="2" width="300" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" summary="">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
              <td colspan="4" align="center"><b>Order Form</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th align="right">Extension</th>
          </tr>
                        <tr>
              <td><input name="line" type="text" size="10" value="" onkeyup="count(this.form,0,5.49)"></td>
                        <th>Apples</th><td class="right">$5.49</td><td align="right"><input name="line_sum" type="text" size="10" id="apples_total" readonly></td>
          </tr>
                        <tr>
              <td><input name="line" type="text" size="10" value="" onkeyup="count(this.form,1,7.49)"></td> <th>Pears</th><td class="right">$7.49</td>
                        <td align="right"><input name="line_sum" type="text" size="10" id="pears_total" readonly></td></tr>
                        <tr>
              <td><input name="line" type="text" size="10" value="" onkeyup="count(this.form,2,6.49)">
                        </td><th>Grapes</th><td class="right">$6.49</td><td align="right"><input name="line_sum" type="text" size="10" id="grapes_total" readonly></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input name="line" type="text" size="10" value="" onkeyup="count(this.form,3,)"></td>
                        <th colspan="2" align="right">Totals</th><td><input name="line" type="text" size="10" id="sub_total" readonly"></td></tr>
                        <tr><th colspan="3" align="right"> Tax @ 6%</th><td><input name="line" type="text" size="10" id="tax_total" readonly></td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="1" align="center"><input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="get_data(this.form)"></td><th colspan="2" align="right"> Final Total</th><td><input name="line_sum" type="text" size="10" id="grand_total" readonly>
            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working on this, but I just want to say for the love of all things programming, DO NOT USE SINGLE LETTER VARIABLE NAMES. Thank you =)

Comment: NaN means not a number. Do a console.log(gt) and find out why it has not the value you expect

Answer (score 0):

you are making strings by adding ".00" this is highly impractical.

use numbers to deal with.. well.. math in general :P

```
parseFloat(YourVariable).toFixed(2)
```

also, keep in mind if you have polluted data in there and you may have odd stuff like "FREE" instead of an actual number, you can check beforehand like this

```
if(isNaN(YourVariable)){
    return "moo! this is pollution and my code should be green!";
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: As soon as I put in the parseFloats, it stopped doing calculations altogether? Do I put them in the function where I defined my variables like var apples = 0 + document.getElementById("apples_total").value and then add the parseFloat or do I need to open a new function?

Comment: i need to move home, ill answer you later with the code integrated to the one you left in the question, sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 0):

This is what causes the `NaN`:

The *grand_total* input has the *line_sum* class, and as a consequence it gets processed to take part in the sum of the total. But that input is where the total is put! Since you prefix that sum with a dollar, it causes the `NaN` to appear the very next time the sum is calculated again.

Solve this by removing that class from that input element.

Then you also have these issues:

- A syntax error in `onkeyup="count(this.form,3,)` -- the third argument is missing.
- An undefined variable *f*, which probably should be *a* instead